# ClientToWorld value when not interacting with model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there a method similar to ClientToWorld, that can give me the X,Y world coords if I provide it with X,Y screen coords?

I know that ClientToWorld gives me a Z coord of where it interacts with the model, but I am happy to have no Z coord as it will not raycast to a point on the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `Viewer3dImpl.clientToViewport`?

```
let coords = viewer.impl.clientToViewport(client.x, client.y); //c.Vector3 {x: -0.9696521095484826, y: 0.9200779727095516, z: 1 (always 1)}
let finalCoords = coords.unproject(viewer.impl.camera) //c.Vector3 {x: -26.379134321221724, y: 5.162777223710702, z: 1.3846547842336627}
```

See **unofficial doc (not authoritative & subject to change w/o notice)** for this method [here](https://autodesk-forge.gitee.io/helpcenter/classes/autodesk.viewing.private.viewer3dimpl.html#clienttoviewport)

Comment: I also had to use: point.unproject(viewer.impl.camera) to get the final coords after using clientToViewport